# FLASK : plotly : Error: module 'index' has no attribute 'app.server'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly-dash, vscode-debugger

## the context

I am debugging an application using Visual Studio Code (VSCode).

- The application relies mainly on https://plot.ly, https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask, https://pandas.pydata.org/ and https://numpy.org/

### Breakpoints ARE NOT hit!

- The breakpoints ARE NOT hit when I am using the launch.json (See [1])
- I can debug with this launch.json (See [2]) but the debugger does not stops at the breakpoint !

**I would like VSCode to stop on my breakpoints when necessary**

**What is the correct configuration for launch.json to hit the breakpoints? **

Thank you for the time you are investing helping me!

#### the hierarchy of the project

> - launch.json
> - index.py See [4]
> - app.py See [3]
> - pages
>
>   - index.py
>   - transactions.py

- launch.json is described here below [1]

## the issue : Error: module 'index' has no attribute 'app.server'

The Error message is displayed after clicking on 'Start debugging > F5' = **Error: module 'index' has no attribute 'app.server'**

I tried dozens of ways to set the **"FLASK_APP": "index:app.server"** but they generate diverse error messages :

- **"FLASK_APP": "index:app.server"** generates this error **Error: A valid Flask application was not obtained from "index:app".**
- **"FLASK_APP": "index.py"** generates this error **Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "index". Use "FLASK_APP=index:name to specify one.**

### for information : gunicorn command (working)

here is a command available in `azure-pipelines.yml` running the plotly app :

- `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 index:app.server`

## attached files

### [1] launch.json - non working

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "index:app.server",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1",
                "FLASK_RUN_PORT": "8052"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

### [2] launch.json - working but breakpoints are not hit

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\index.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

### [3] webapp.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport",
                          "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}]
)
server = app.server
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True
```

### index.py - root of the application

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from webapp import app
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from pages import (
    transactions, index)


# Describe the layout/ UI of the app
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id="url", refresh=False),
    html.Div(id="page-content")
])


# Update page
@app.callback(Output("page-content", "children"),
              [Input("url", "pathname")])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/dash/index":
        return index.layout
    if pathname == "/dash/transactions":
        return transactions.layout
    else:
        return index.layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [1] example isn't working because you set `FLASK_APP` to `index:app.server` which tries to find an attribute named `app.server` on the `index` module. Attribute names can't have a dot (you can verify this by importing that module and trying out `getattr(index, "app.server")`). You should be able to make `FLASK_APP` simply say `index` to have it work.

See the [Flask documentation on app discovery](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/?highlight=flask_app#application-discovery) for more details.